# Prove that$ \frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n} \in$ Z

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Using permutation or otherwise, prove that$ \frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}$an integer, where n is a positive integer.

Putting n=1,2,3.... I can prove that above quantity is an integer but this is not correct as it needs to be proved in a methodological way.

Comment: Thanks I will mark it as duplicate

Comment: ;It can be proven with very easy high-school knowledge. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467574/using-permutation-or-otherwise-prove-that-fracn2nn-is-an-integer/2416194#2416194